# Why does this sentence use 'so' and 'of' here?

Tags: word-usage

When I was doing my translation homework, I met a sentence as below:

European architecture in the years immediately before World War I is in some ways more notable for abortive projects and visionary designs than for actual buildings, most startling ***so*** in the unrealized projects ***of*** Antonio, who was killed in the war.

Why does here use the 'so' and the 'of'? Is there some special use?
Any suggestion shall be appreciated!

Comment: 'So' is doubtless the 'in this respect' synonym here, but I've only ever seen it after 'more' or 'more **adverb** so'.  I'm not sure of the grammaticalitry here. // The 'of' is the usual sense. The plays of Shakespeare.

Comment: Let's start with projects of Antonio, simpler. Those projects belonged to him, perhaps he was a builder or architect. *So* takes the place of all this: abortive projects and visionary designs. No wonder the writer wrote *so*.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't _most startlingly so_? The unrealized projects of Antonio are the most startling example of [what the first part of the sentence says]. In the context of architecture, _unrealized projects_ would be unfinished buildings designed by Antonio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's simplify your sentence (just for purposes of illustration):

> *European architecture is more notable for visionary designs than for actual buildings—most startlingly* so in the unrealized projects of
>   Antonio.*

Now we can more easily see how *so* is functioning here. Some dictionaries call it a pronoun in this sense—because it is a substitute for an antecedent (never mind that the antecedent is not a noun). The OED calls it adverb.

> **so** *pronoun*
>   **1 :** such as has been specified or suggested : the same
>       <sub>// if you have to file a claim, do so as soon
>   as possible</sub>
>
> <sub>Source:
>   [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so)</sub>

In the above example, *so* stands for *file a claim*:

> <sub>// If you have to file a claim, [do] file a claim as soon as possible.</sub>

In your sentence, *so* stands in for the entire previous phrase *more notable for visionary designs than for actual building*. Like this:

> *European architecture is more notable for visionary designs than for actual buildings—most startlingly more notable for visionary designs
>   than for actual buildings in the unrealized projects of Antonio.*

By now you can see that *the unrealized projects of Antonio* simply means *Antonio's unrealized projects*.

---

<sub>* You need an adverb form here—*startingly*, not *startling*.</sub>